# Exploring the WSDL through tools

Tags: java, web-services

I have got the wsdl from client for a webservice , Now I want to test that wsdl , from google I have explored a tool named Soap UI , through which we can test our web service plus it will generate the client code for us also, Please tell me what other tools are available that will help me to explore that wsdl from testing plus generating the client code or any other functionality also.

Answer (score 3):

If your main goal is to do testing IMHO `SoapUI` is the best tool. If you need to invoke the service programatically doing it in Eclise is the best option.

You can check this link on [SOAP Tools](http://www.soapclient.com/SoapTools.html)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse, for instance, has a [Web Services Explorer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Web_Service_Explorer_to_test_a_Web_service) tool that is quite useful for testing web services. You can also [generate a client](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf) with it.

You can easily generate clients with the [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) WS libraries' `wsdl2java`.